# I get an error" No application can perform this action" while sending an email

Tags: android, android-intent

Here is the code, everythin works well except the no application can perform this action "error..Please let me know what  is the mistake in the code.

```
 public void sends(View button) {   
        // Do click handling here  


        final EditText date = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);  
        String da = date.getText().toString();  

        final EditText phone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);  
        String ph = phone.getText().toString();  

        final EditText nameplate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);  
        String np = nameplate.getText().toString(); 

        final EditText issue = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);  
        String i = issue.getText().toString(); 

        StringBuilder s= new StringBuilder(100);
        s.append(da);
        s.append(". ");
        s.append(ph);
        s.append(". ");
        s.append(np);
        s.append(". ");
        s.append(i);

        String st=s.toString();




        Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
        //emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
        //startActivity(emailIntent); 
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send your email in:"));

        Intent emailIntentt= new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);  

        String aEmailList[] = { "shreyas.tallani@gmail.com" };  


        emailIntentt.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, aEmailList);  
        //emailIntentt.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_CC, aEmailCCList);  
        //emailIntentt.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_BCC, aEmailBCCList);  

        emailIntentt.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Feedback");  

        emailIntentt.setType("message/rfc822");  
        emailIntentt.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, st);




        startActivityForResult(emailIntentt, REQUEST_SEND_MAIL);
    } 
    public static final int REQUEST_SEND_MAIL = 1;

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {



        switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_SEND_MAIL:
            // When the request to send mail returns
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "message successfully sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "sorry", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            }}
```

Comment: there is no email application setup on the device you are running on!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `startActivity()` and `startActivityForResult`!!! You need one. That's why the first intent gets fired and there is no app to catch it.

Try this:

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);   
String aEmailList[] = { "shreyas.tallani@gmail.com" };  

emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, aEmailList); 
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Feedback");   
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, st);

startActivityForResult(emailIntent, REQUEST_SEND_MAIL);
```

Comment: Thanks :) the problem now is while sending an email the options like send your email in "gmail etc" wont come up.. But it's ok coz the intention is to send an email n dat works n it to the mentioned email id

Comment: You mean you can't choose from different apps? Or do you mean you can't specify a title for your chooser?

Comment: I am not gettin dose options for ex "send an email in gmail, hotmail " somethin like dis.. Hope u got it

Comment: Change your last line like this: startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(emailIntentt, label),REQUEST_SEND_MAIL);

Answer (score 4):

This helped me:

```
String email = person.getEmail();
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
intent.setType("message/rfc822");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{email});
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Happy Birthday!");
intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:" + email));
context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send e-mail to"));
```

There are many answers about Uri.fromParts() method, but the only thing that helped after hours of headache Uri.parse();

By clicking i get all email apps installed on my phone.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say your problem is that `emailIntentt.setType("message/rfc822");`. Set the type to `"plain/text"`.

Also don't start two activities, one will be enough, simply use the chooser.

Comment: I had tried plain/Text.. Still it didn't work..:( so I tried message/rfc822.. But still no use .. I get the same error :(

Answer (score 1):

remove either startActivity() or startActivityForResult()

Answer (score 0):

2 Suggestions i got for u:

1, Run it in a Google API targeted emulator or run it in a device

2, first sign in ur email account before u run this app :)

cheers

Comment: See [this](http://mooriandroid.blogspot.in/p/email-attachment-from.html) example, hope this helps :)